# Is it haram to showcase a wine project on a website for work?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, alcohol

My current company has given me a project to showcase a wine project on their website. I have not created the site but I am putting it on their website's showcase (Since its done by the company). Will it be haram to do it?

Comment: I think its better to avoid, because at-least it is promoting wine in some way. And a muslim should not be a part of it. You can firmly say no, i am sure they have other resources who can do so. And for future, i would advise you to look for a better place of work if you deal with this kind of stuff regularly

Answer (score -1):

it's difficult to say to be sure. But, of course, an expert a'lim should answer on it.

Meanwhile, I can suggest you a bypass to avoid the consequence; just in case you can't just leave the job due to your circumstances, or you can't avoid the task.

How much time or effort you have to give to do the task (make it on to website), calculate it. Let's say, 3 hours. Now, take your total hour-input in a month; usually it is 160 hours a month. Or, you can use weekly hours. 
Now, you can decide what you are getting paid for **that 3 hours**.

Donate (sadaka) that money to someone very bad financial condition (Muslim or non-muslim); but without any hope of reward from Allah (swt).

Please note again this is not an "answer", rather a bypass suggestion which is too big as an comment.

Allah (SWT) knows the best.

Comment: @aboudi good observation. Actually I've used the word "bypass" basically to outplay my own ignorance; not to outsmart Allah swt. I've used the word with meaning like heart's "bypass" surgery, which is an emergency manuever. Anyway, as a non-native speaker of English, maybe I'm missing some subtlety.